# Apply formula if meet criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data set:

```
df1 <- list(
  x = seq(0,100, length.out = 1500),
  y = seq(0,500, length.out = 1500),
  z = rep(letters[1], length.out = 1500)
) 

df2 <- list(
  x = seq(0,100, length.out = 1480),
  y = seq(400,800, length.out = 1480),
  z = rep(letters[2], length.out = 1480)
)

df3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

I need to apply a function in `df3`, let's say, I need to divide the column `y` by **200** if it meets the criterion of `z == 'b'`.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: `df3 %>% mutate(y = ifelse(z == 'b', y / 200, y))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `case_when` which is extendible to more than two cases.

```html
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df3 %>% 
     mutate(y = case_when(z=="b" ~ y / 200,
                          TRUE ~ y))
```